# error connecting F# to SQL

Tags: sql, f#

I'm trying to connect F# to SQL but when i build I keep getting this error

---

> Warning   3   The primary reference "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders" could not
>   be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET
>   Framework assembly "FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.3.0.0"
>   than the version "4.0.0.0" in the current target
>   framework.    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  1360    9   ConsoleApplication33

---

Where can I find this version FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0? or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you targeting .NET Framework 4.5? If you target .NET Framework 4.5 and create a new project, Visual Studio automatically makes a reference to FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0 which belongs to F# 3.0.

Somehow, you mistakenly added a reference to FSharp.Core version in F# 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.0. Therefore, first check `Target Framework` in Project `Properties` and then add FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0 using `Reference` dialog (notice there are various FSharp.Core versions).

Comment: Incidentally, is it possible to use 4.3.0.0 in a project targeting .NET 4.0? I guess I should just try it, because it would be handy to have F# 3's LINQ support in a certain .NET 4 project I can think of...

Comment: @JoelMueller: It's like using FSharp.Core 4.0.0.0 with .NET 2.0/3.5. I don't think there is any problem with that. You should try and see :-)

Comment: @pad thank you very much -that was very helpfull.I guess I'll wait for the .NET Framework 4.5 beta release tomorrow then.